# Why does this recursive sum function not work correctly?

Tags: c, recursion, cs50

There is this Mario problem in the [CS50](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CS50) course and it's easy using the recursion method, except that when I try to add any arithmetic operation it shows (invalid operands to binary expression ('void' and 'int')). It's just for the sake of me to understand what I can do using recursion and what I can't; the problem is this line (`sum(n-1)+n;`)

Here is the code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void sum(int n);

int main ()
{
    int u = get_int("f");
    sum (u);
}

void sum(int n)
{
  if (n==0)
  {
    return;
  }
  sum(n-1)+n;
  for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
  {
    printf( "#");
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: What does the function try to do?

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing is from this line:

```
sum(n-1)+n;
```

**sum** is a function that returns **void**, but you are trying to add it with an integer n.

I am not quite sure what that get_int("f") does, but I assume it's prompting to the user for an int input, and you are trying to sum from 0 to that number. Here is the solution:

```
int sum(int n) // Here is the critical change to your code, now it returns an int
{
  if (n == 1) // Root case that will stop the recursion, otherwise, it's endless
    return 1; // 1 = 1 + 0;

  return sum(n-1) + n; // Recursion
}
```

Think about what we are trying to achieve here. We want to add from 0 to n, or to say from n to 0 downwards. If n is 3, it's going to be 3+2+1+0, and you'll notice that 3 is just n, and 2 is n - 1, 1 is (n - 1) - 1, etc. To visualize it:

1. before sum(3) could return anything, it calls sum(2) + 3;
2. before sum(2) could return anything, it calls sum(1) + 2;
3. 1 is our root case, and there is no more calls, so sum(1) is going to return 1;
4. that 1 is returned to step 2, so sum(1) + 2 becomes 1 + 2, which is 3, and that is the value sum(2), and it returns its result to step 1, and step 1 becomes 3 + 3, which is 6, and the initial call to sum is then completed.

I hope that makes sense to you. Recursion is not an easy technique to master. Take your time, but you need to understand how function calls work in memory. Here is a video that illustrates how recursive calls in memory look like, *[Data Structures Using C++: Illustration of Recursive Function Calls (Call Stack)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0bb7UYy0pY)*.

Comment: thank u very much for your response ,  in fact  i dont fully understand recursion and thank u for the link i will watch it now actually ,  i just wanna  add that in this  code i want to print  (#) a number of times that is calculated from sum ( n-1)+n; so why cant i keep the void function coz i dont want any int to be returned i just need it to be calculated and print the # sign that is why i use void and even if i use int instead of void still i get the same error

Comment: @ahmednabil hey, it returns the int for its own usage, you don't really have to mind that, and you can totally put print statements inside them. Also, void functions in recursion are rare, because you can't compute anything, it simply calls itself without knowing the result of last call, unless you pass that computed value along or keep it as a global variable. It is useful when you are going through a linked list and trying to get to the last element, you can do something like this, void func(Node* node) { if (node == nullptr) { dosomething non-recursive;} else func(node->next); }

Answer (score 0):

It is because the return type of the function `sum()` is `void`.

You cannot add anything to `void`.

Anyway the result of the "addition" is thrown away, so you won't need addition.

This mean that `sum ( n-1)+n;` should be replaced with `sum ( n-1);`.

Comment: thank u for your response , i have a question why the addition is thrown away < in my mindi picture it to add n after finding the number from sum(n-1) and to us e this int to print # with tha may of times that was just being estimated ? can u illustrate plz?

Comment: The `sum` function must be rewritten to return a value.